# Get all elements inside a specific node

Tags: java, xml

I'm new to XML parsing and I'm lost. First, here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
    <data>
        <food type="none">
            <price>100</price>
        </food>
        <food type="none">
            <price>50</price>
        </food>
    </data>

    <trash>
        <food type="none" id="1"/>
        <food type="none" id="2"/>
    </trash>
</menu>
```

I'm trying to parse this XML. I want to get all **food** items inside **data**.

When I do:

```
NodeList nUsines = doc.getElementsByTagName("food");
```

I also get the **food** items in **trash**, but I don't want this.

And sorry if my questions sounds off, I don't know the proper terms for XML

My code so far (inside a method):

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(file.getPath());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nUsines = doc.getElementsByTagName("food");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath (just one of the options):

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//data/food");

System.out.println(((NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has done exactly what you asked it to.

You want a more specific query, such as `food` elements within the `data` element.

You could try to select the `data` element, then query for `food` elements specifically within that.

Alternatively, look up XPath, and you'll quickly find another way to do this.

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me the code to select the data element? I've tried everything

Comment: You've clearly not tried everything. You already know how to select all `food` elements, so you also know how to select all `data` elements.

Comment: System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement()); returns [menu : null]

Comment: And NodeList nData = doc.getElementsByTagName("data"); length returns 0

Comment: Are you sure? If the code in your question gives you the `food` elements, using `data` instead of `food` should give you a list with the `data` element in it.